# Slidify - add class to title slide

Tags: css, yaml, slidify

I created a custom css file to adjust the layout of my slides created with slidify. 
I was wondering if I could add a class to the title slide.
I tried the following:

```
    --- .className
    title       : test
    subtitle    : test
    author      : test
    job         : test
    framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
    highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
    hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
    widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
    mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
    knit        : slidify::knit2slides
```

Unfortunately I get the following error code:

```
    Error in yaml.load(txt) : 
    Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2, column 13
```

Does anybody know how to do it properly?

Comment: The deault class is `title-slide`. I've tried to add a class at the end of the YAML (and begining of the first slide) with out success. I would be nice to know why do you need to add a class to the first slide. You can find the "css file (it's slidify.css)" in this path: `your-deck\libraries\frameworks\io2012\css`